# HttpServlet is set to null in struts2

Tags: struts2, struts-1

I am a newbie for struts. I have a requirement to Migrate from struts1 to struts2 application. I have to pass `HttpServlet` to one service which was already written in struts1 application.  My controller has:

```
class myController{ 
HttpServletRequest request; 
HttpServlet servlet; 
}
```

where 
HttpServletRequest request= org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsRequestWrapper but HttpServlet servlet = null
Since my service takes servlet as input parameter I am not able to get the output value as servlet is null. 
Is there any way in Struts2 to set HttpServlet value? Please suggest.

Comment: How do you want  to get the output value from `servlet`?